# typo3 extbase use toArray in an phpunit test

Tags: mocking, phpunit, typo3, extbase

I have an extbase-extension (typo3 4.5) with

```
$test = $this->testRepository->findAll();
$this->view->assign('test', 
    array_merge(
        array('0' => 'select'), 
        $test->toArray()
    )
);
```

it works very well, but i want to test the code and mock the findAll-method of my testrepository. I dont know which type i must return to have the toArray-method

```
...
$method->will($this->returnValue(array($testModelObject)));
...
```

Of course my unittest throws an error: "Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object"

Answer (score 0):

Simply `var_dump()` your real `$test` object, and you will see the class.

Comment: I already know that it is of type Tx_Extbase_Persistence_QueryResult, but i dont know how to initialize it in my Test.

Comment: Your question is: "dont know which type i must return to have the toArray-method"

Comment: yes. i can not return an array. and the Tx_Extbase_Persistence_QueryResult needs some configuartion and i dont know how.